# how to convert a list of image URLs to a zip file of images?

Tags: image, url, amazon-s3, jpeg, batch-processing

Does anyone know how to batch download images relying only just a list of image URLs as the data source? I've looked through applications but all I could find was this: http://www.page2images.com/ (which only hardcodes a screenshot of every image on the URLs.)

Comment: You could use `wget` (depending on your operating system of course). Or `curl`.

Comment: I have mac. I look into curl. I didn't know if can go through URLs at batch. I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So have a server running whatever you'd like.

1. Send an array of image names to the server - use whatever language you want but have the function do a for loop over the array
2. Execute `wget https://image.png` from the file (let's say you use NodeJS, this would be `eval('wget ' + imgList[i])` - this will download everything to your current directory
3. Once the for loop is finished, the next step is to zip all your items `tar -zcvf files.tar.gz ./` - this will create a tar ball of all the files within that directory

   4. Download that tar

If you want to get fancy with this, you should create a randomly named directory and execute all your commands to point inside that directory. So you would say `wget https://image.png ./jriyxjendoxh/` to get the file into the randomly named folder. Then at the end `tar -zcvf files.tar.gz jriyxjendoxh/*`

Then to make sure you have all the files downloaded, you can create a semaphore to put a block on the creation of the tar ball until the number of files is equal to the count of the passed in array. That would be a real fancy way to make sure all the files are downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there You could try free download manager or if you have Linux use the wget command with the text source file